# Pause comma before "but"

Tags: grammar

My understanding is that I should only use a comma before "but" if it precedes an independent clause.

What if I want a "pause comma" before "but" and it does not precede an independent clause?

**Example**:

One day, Ted thought he saw another boy dancing, but it was just the reflection of himself.

Comment: The clause 'it was just the reflection of himself.' _**is**_ independent.

Comment: I'd say the comma (pause, in speech) is effectively *required* in your context, where the ***but-*** clause is effectively a ***whole sentence adverb*** (contrastive ***but*** applies to the entire preceding text, not just the preceding ***word***). You wouldn't have a comma or pause if ***but*** only applied to the actual word before it, as in *...he saw another boy **dancing but not singing**.*